# std::function incomplete type on const function

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std-function

Consider the following code which works as expected:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct foo
{
    std::function<int()> get;
};

struct bar
{
    int get()
    {
        return 42;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo f;
    bar b;
    f.get = std::bind(&bar::get, &b);

    if (f.get())
        std::cout << "f.get(): " << f.get() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now, let's assume that `bar::get()` is a const member function:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct foo
{
    std::function<int()const> get;
};

struct bar
{
    int get() const
    {
        return 42;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo f;
    bar b;
    f.get = std::bind(&bar::get, &b);

    if (f.get())
        std::cout << "f.get(): " << f.get() << std::endl;
}
```

Using GCC 9.2, this snipped throws the following compiler error:

```
main.cpp:6:31: error: field 'get' has incomplete type 'std::function<int() const>'
    6 |     std::function<int()const> get;
      |                               ^~~
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/functional:59,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/std_function.h:128:11: note: declaration of 'class std::function<int() const>'
  128 |     class function;
      |           ^~~~~~~~
```

I fail to understand why `foo::get` has incomplete type.
Could somebody point me towards the right direction for understanding this behavior and "fixing" it accordingly?
I have the need to bind a const member function to a function pointer.

Comment: So you want `const std::function<int()> get;`? Or do you want `int (bar::*get)() const;`? The constness is checked at `std::bind`, not at `std::function`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int()const` is an [abominable type](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/p0172r0.html).

`std::function<int()const>` is not a type, because it doesn't match the [only defined specialisation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

```
namespace std {
    template< class R, class... Args >
    class function<R(Args...)> { ... };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `std::function<int()>`.

The `const` bit only makes sense for member functions. You've already bound `bar::get` to an instance `b` to save it as a `std::function`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::bind` does not pass through `const`ness to the callable. Therefore, the following would work:

```cpp
struct foo {
    std::function<int()> get;
    //                 ^ note there is no 'const'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @KamilCuk:

> The constness is checked at std::bind, not at std::function

You don't need to pass `explicit` const to `std::function`. Just use your older prototype: `std::function<int()>`. It will work if you don't have const overload (that mean, you have either one of these `int bar::get()` or `int bar::get() const`) for the same member function (Otherwise, you need to type cast explicity).

Actually, your function (`int bar::get() const`) will be having a signature like this (behind the scenes):

```
// int bar::get() const
int get(const bar *const this)
{
    return 42;
}

// int bar::get() 
int get(bar *const this)
{
    return 42;
}
```

If you have overloads and want to bind specific member function, you can do something like this:

```
typedef int(bar::*fptr)(void) const; // or remove const
std::bind((fptr)&bar::get, &b );
```

See this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

struct foo
{
    std::function<int()> get;
};

struct bar
{
    int get()
    {
        return 42;
    }

    int get() const
    {
        return 50;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo f;
    bar b;
    typedef int (bar::*fptr)(void);
    typedef int (bar::*fcptr)(void) const;
    f.get = std::bind((fptr)&bar::get, &b);

    if (f.get())
        std::cout << "f.get(): " << f.get() << std::endl;

    f.get = std::bind((fcptr)&bar::get, &b);

    if (f.get())
        std::cout << "f.get(): " << f.get() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
f.get(): 42
f.get(): 50
```